# How to remove Lyrics3 v2 tag from id3?

Tags: vb.net, metadata, id3, taglib-sharp

I use the taglib sharp library to remove all tags from my songs with the command

```
Track = TagLib.File.Create("C:\test\Super Trouper.mp3")
Track.RemoveTags(TagLib.TagTypes.AllTags)
Track.Save()
Track.Dispose()
```

Unfortunately, the `.RemoveTags` doesn't remove a Lyrics3 v2.0 tag
(specified here: http://id3.org/Lyrics3v2).

*Such a tag can be detected with a tool like "Mp3 Diags" (http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/)*

How can I completely remove ALL tags and ALL frames from my song?

Or how can I remove this specific Lyrics3 v2 tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, TagLib# doesn't support Lyrics3 tags. In an MP3 file, TagLib# will detect and can remove only APE, Id3v1, and Id3v2 tags.

After saving the file with tags removed by TagLib#, you could do something like the following with your own code:

1. Open a file stream.
2. Seek to Length - 9, read 9 bytes and see if they equal `LYRICS200` or `LYRICSEND`.  If not, close the file.
3. Seeking back 11 bytes.
4. Reading 11 bytes and checking if they match `LYRICSBEGIN`. If so, truncate the file at that point.
5. If not, keep seeking back 1 byte and repeating step 4.  Probably give up after 10KB or so.

This is not the most efficient strategy but I'm imagining the number of files with these tags is quite low so most should stop after step 2.

Comment: That works. Thank you, Brian. Do you know if the Lyrics3 tag will ever be supported in TagLib#? The last official version 2.1.0 was released more then 2 years ago, AFAIK.

Comment: Probably not.  The project appears to be maintain-only (at best) and if it were active the Lyrics3 tag is still pretty obscure and doesn't really fit with the rest of the tagging scheme. TagLib# does support the ID3v2.3 Synchronized Lyrics frame via [SynchronizedLyricsFrame](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/a5f6949a53d09ce63ee7495580d6802921a21f14/src/TagLib/Id3v2/Frames/SynchronizedLyricsFrame.cs).  Not sure how broadly that's supported elsewhere though.

Comment: If someone is interested on a solution then please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963163/is-it-possible-using-taglibsharp-to-remove-a-lyrics3v2-tag-from-a-mp3-file/37068114#37068114