# Is it possible, using TagLibSharp, to remove a Lyrics3v2 tag from a MP3 file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mp3, taglib-sharp

I wonder if it's possible to remove a **Lyrics3v2** tag type from a MP3 file using **[TagLibSharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp)** library.

**[This](http://id3.org/Lyrics3v2)** documentation says that the block entry starts with word "**LYRICSBEGIN**" and ends with "**LYRICS200**", also it says that the ID3 tag should be present to let exists the **Lyrics3v2** tag ...but it doesn't specifies if reffers to **ID3v1** or **ID3v2** tag, or any of them, anyways I don't understand that part, because **Lyrics3v2** tag is a single tag type, is not part of an **ID3v1/ID3v2** tag type, it has its own entry on the mp3 header so... I don't understand what it means about the **ID3v1/ID3v2** "dependancy".

Anyways assuming that info is correct, then I should be able to use **TagLibSharp** to remove the **ID3v1** and **ID3v2** tags from the mp3 file containing the **Lyrics3v2** tag then that tag will be removed too?, however, the tag still exists.

Also, the `Lyrics` property that exposes **TagLibSharp**'s classes seems doesn't affect to the **Lyrics3v2** tag, all this is very confussing.

Comment: This question should be reopened, first of all my question is specific to a specific library, not to mp3 structure itself, and secondlly, I wrote a working solution using taglibsharp but I can't share the answer since my question is blocked. I just really would like to publish the solution, a moderator can block it after that.

Comment: If they don't reopen your question, please add your working solution to the other linked question as a second answer. I would really like to see your solution! Thanks.

Comment: @PeterCo I published it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671210/how-to-remove-lyrics3-v2-tag-from-id3/36974341#36974341 I hope it can be usefull for you, or for someone else.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: I have reopened the question. You can now delete your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/q/26671210/444991, and repost it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this solution using `taglibsharp`:

```
' *************************************************************
' THIS CLASS IS PARTIALLY DEFINED FOR THIS STACKOVERFLOW ANSWER
' *************************************************************

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports TagLib

''' <summary>
''' Represents the <c>Lyrics3</c> tag for a MP3 file.
''' </summary>
Public Class Lyrics3Tag

    Protected ReadOnly mp3File As Mpeg.AudioFile

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The maximum length for the <c>Lyrics3</c> block to prevent issues like removing a false-positive block of data.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Note that this is a personal attempt to prevent catastrophes, not based on any official info.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly maxLength As Integer = 512 ' bytes

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal mp3File As Mpeg.AudioFile)
        Me.mp3File = mp3File
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Entirely removes the <c>Lyrics3</c> tag.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Sub Remove()

        Dim initVector As New ByteVector(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LYRICSBEGIN"))
        Dim initOffset As Long = Me.mp3File.Find(initVector, startPosition:=0)

        If (initOffset <> -1) Then

            ' The Lyrics3 block can end with one of these two markups, so we need to evaluate both.
            For Each str As String In {"LYRICS200", "LYRICSEND"}

                Dim endVector As New ByteVector(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
                Dim endOffset As Long = Me.mp3File.Find(endVector, startPosition:=initOffset)

                If (endOffset <> -1) Then

                    Dim length As Integer = CInt(endOffset - initOffset) + (str.Length)
                    If (length < Me.maxLength) Then
                        Try
                            Me.mp3File.Seek(initOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                            ' Dim raw As String = Me.mp3File.ReadBlock(length).ToString()
                            Me.mp3File.RemoveBlock(initOffset, length)
                            Exit Sub

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Throw

                        Finally
                            Me.mp3File.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

                        End Try

                    Else ' Length exceeds the max length.
                         ' We can handle it or continue...
                        Continue For

                    End If

                End If

            Next str

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Example usage:

```
Dim mp3File As New Taglib.Mpeg.AudioFile("filepath")

Using lyrics As New Lyrics3Tag(mp3File)
    lyrics.Remove()
End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [How to remove Lyrics3 v2 tag from id3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671210/how-to-remove-lyrics3-v2-tag-from-id3) the answer is "No". You will find a workaround in the <del>linked</del> answer below.